# Android 2.3.5 unlock screen activated unexpectedly

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, settings, lock-screens

My Android HTC Sense 3.5 running Android 2.3.5 suddenly and out of the blue activates the unlock screen without pressing the power button. That's a problem because it gets unlocked by itself sometimes when it is in my pocket. Is there a special setting to disable this activation of the unlock screen?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this happens, but you may be able to combat the problem with [Proximity AutoLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuts.autolock&hl=en).  If the phone's screen is somehow turned on, the proximity sensor should tell the phone to turn its screen off right away.  Now, this works when the power button gets pressed; I would think it would also work when other events turn the screen on, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a screen lock that requires more that a keystroke to unlock the phone, as to prevent the phone being unlocked when bouncing around inside your pockets:

1. Click your phone "menu" button;
2. Tap "Settings";
3. Tap "Location & security";
4. Scroll your way to "Screen unlock" and tap over "Set up screen lock";
5. Pick your *poison*, for me it was "Pattern";

After selecting a more robust method to unlock your screen, even if the unlock screen pops up while the phone is in your pocket, it will be virtually impossible unlock the phone that way.

Comment: This could work.  I would think an 'L' shaped pattern wouldn't be too much harder than a simple swipe. Is there a limit on how many pattern tries you can have?

Comment: @Chance After 5 attempts, the device forces a period of 30 seconds before allowing more attempts, and if the notification doesn't get dismissed, the 30 seconds period doesn't start the count down.

Comment: Agree.  I just wondered if his phone is becoming unlocked in his pocket via a swipe action, if an incorrect 2-dot pattern would be possible in his pocket, as well.  But the odds of this happening 5 times would be low, I think.  But yes, it would be impossible for the pin screen to be bypassed.